# TeeChart for Mono Android will not compile

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android, teechart

I just downloaded the TeeChart trial version for Mono Android using the installation as below:

> TeeChartMfAEval-4.0.2012.121203-win.exe

I am running Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate on Windows 8. I am trying to build the demo project, but am getting the error below:

> The type 'Android.Widget.FrameLayout' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Mono.Android,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4c4237547e4b6cd'.

I also get the same error if I try add the TeeChart assembly to my main project, which is for an established app, so clearly the reference to Mono.Android is fine. For example, the following code:

```
Android.Widget.FrameLayout fl;
Steema.TeeChart.TChart tChart;
```

throws up a compilation error on the second line.

Any ideas?

### Update:

It turns out that if you download the trial library from the Xamarin Components webpage, then the library is more up to date and indeed works. I was downloading from the TeeChart website 'Downloads' area, which is obviously out of date.

Thanks to CheeseBaron for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Where did you get that file from? Was it at Steema Software's website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steema Software's [eval download page](http://www.steema.com/download/mobile) includes a link to Build 4.13.03.04, much newer than yours, which fixes this problem. The explanation to the issue are the [Changes to Assembly strongnames in Xamarin.Android 4.6.0](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1476/changes-to-assembly-strongnames-in-xamarin-android-4-6-0). This made necessary for us to make another build of TeeChart.Android.dll. Users needed to update their project references as well.

Comment: You are quite right. I missed that somehow as I was searching for MfA.

Comment: @bellissimo no problem. We changed product names to go in the same line as Xamarin product naming.

Answer (score 2):

It is because Xamarin changed the names of their assemblies in a recent version, from Mono.Android to Xamarin.Android. The TeeChart folks need to recompile their projects against the new version.

I'd suggest you to contact them and tell them about this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will send them an email.